# How to represent non sequential code in UML?

Tags: multithreading, callback, uml, diagram, sequential

I can't find any UML diagram to represent non sequential code(e.g. callbacks, code running on different threads).

Is it possible to represent non sequential code in an UML diagram? Is there a non-sequence diagram?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram

Answer (score 5):

Actually, a [sequence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) is what you are looking for. It shows multiple objects and how they interact. Each object has a specific timeline. The word "sequence" does not refer to the code but how the messages between times (communication between objects) are sequenced.

As @xmojmr points out:

> an [activity diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram)
>   can also be used: it focuses on operations (interesting also for
>   multiple threads with "swimlanes")

There is a 1:1 mapping between both diagram types. While SDs focus on the time line (which goes strictly top down), ADs focus on message overview (a bit like a mind map).

Comment: Also, sequence diagrams can easily represent asynchronous interactions between objects.  For parallel simultaneous activities such as concurrent threads, activity diagrams with their forks and joins work very well.  Furthermore, sequence diagrams allow detailed modeling of single paths through activity diagrams.

Comment: @MeesterPatat you can find thousands of sequence diagram examples [here](https://repository.genmymodel.com)

Answer (score 0):

If the main problem is multithreading, then the [Timing diagram](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/TimingDiagram.html) can be the most useful.